# Postgres SQL-TG_ARGV within query

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to do a trigger that will verify if a record exists in the table passed as argument. I'm doing it as a laravel migration but nervertheless the SQL should be perceptible

```
DB::unprepared('
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_update_lojas() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_or_update_lojas$
        DECLARE
            store TEXT := TG_ARGV[0]::TEXT;
    BEGIN
        -- Check if product exists
        IF 
            EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TG_ARGV[0]::TEXT WHERE ean = NEW.ean)
        THEN
            UPDATE store SET price_form_factor=NEW.price_form_factor, price_unit=NEW.price_unit WHERE ean=NEW.ean;
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $insert_or_update_lojas$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;');



DB::unprepared('
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_continente BEFORE INSERT ON continente FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_or_update_lojas(\'continente\');');
```

Right now I'm getting

`relation "store" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM store WHERE ean = NEW.ean) ^ QUERY:  SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM store WHERE ean = NEW.ean) CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_or_update_lojas() line 6 at IF`

EDIT:
After googling for the past day i slightly changed the if statement.  `IF  EXECUTE format(\'EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE ean = NEW.ean\', store) THEN EXECUTE (\'UPDATE store SET price_form_factor=NEW.price_form_factor, price_unit=NEW.price_unit WHERE ean=NEW.ean\'); RETURN NULL; END IF;`

I know the format() works. However when I do EXECUTE format() I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 8:                 
EXECUTE format('EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %s WHER...
                                      ^ 
(SQL: 
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_update_lojas() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_or_update_lojas$
            DECLARE
                store TEXT := quote_ident(TG_ARGV[0]);
        BEGIN
            -- Check if product exists
            IF 
                EXECUTE format('EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE ean = NEW.ean', store)
            THEN
                EXECUTE ('UPDATE store SET price_form_factor=NEW.price_form_factor, price_unit=NEW.price_unit WHERE ean=NEW.ean');
                RETURN NULL;
            END IF;
```

Comment: Best guess is the table name is some mixed case like "Store" and since you are not using `quote_ident()` the  argument is being folded to lower case.  There is also the potential future problem of `store TEXT := TG_ARGV[0]::TEXT;` and  `UPDATE store...`. To be clear about what you are doing I would do `_store TEXT := ...`. Before you go any further on migration I would test building the function directly using `psql`.

Comment: Did as you suggeted @AdrianKlaver but I get the same result. The trigger is being called like `DB::unprepared('
        CREATE TRIGGER insert_or_update_continente BEFORE INSERT ON continente FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_or_update_lojas(\'continente\');');` but it still says relation "store" does not exist

Comment: The `format` does not work: `select format(\'EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %s WHERE ean = NEW.ean\', store); invalid command \'EXISTS` what you need is: `select format('EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %I WHERE ean = NEW.ean', 'store');`.  Note the `%I` which is used for identifiers like the table name 'store'. You don't need to spend a day on Google, you need to spend 5-10 minutes here [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) and here [plpgsl dynamic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver, absolutely right in the %I, the escape characterwas because the sql was in a php artisan function. final sql ```CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_or_update_lojas() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_or_update_lojas$
           DECLARE
           store TEXT := quote_ident(TG_ARGV[0]);BEGIN
            IF 
                EXECUTE format('EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %I WHERE ean = NEW.ean', store)
            ........
```    format works correctly, however, when putting EXECUTE it throws ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("LINE 8:EXECUTE format('EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM %I ...
```

Comment: Read this [Exists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)  for where to use `exists`.